# How to unfolding (expand) logical expression?

Tags: logic

How to expand the following expression

```
(b == 0 || b == \[Pi] ) && (a == 0 || a == \[Pi])) || (3 a == 2 \[Pi] && 
   3 b == 4 \[Pi]) || (3 a == 4 \[Pi] && 3 b == 2 \[Pi])
```

to the following solutions?

```
b=0,a=0
b=0,a=\pi
b=\pi,a=0
b=\pi,a=\pi
b=2\pi/4,a=2\pi/3
b=2\pi/3,a=2\pi/4
```

I tried the function LogicalExpand, but it gives me False.

Could anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: Use `Reduce`.  But you'll need to fix your code.  There's an extra `)` in `(a == 0 || a == \[Pi]))` and `\Pi` needs to be changed to `Pi` or `\[Pi]`.

Comment: @JimB Thanks! ```Reduce[((b == 0 || b == \[Pi]) && (a == 0 || a == \[Pi])) || (3 a == 2 \[Pi] && 3 b == 4 \[Pi]) || (3 a == 4 \[Pi] && 3 b == 2 \[Pi])]``` still gives ```false```..

Comment: You must have had previous assignments to `a` and/or `b` (which is what @BobHanlon 's answer with `Clear["Global`*"]` fixes).

Comment: @JimB It works! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

expr = ((b == 0 || b == π) && (a == 0 || a == π)) || (3 a == 2 π &&
      3 b == 4 π) || (3 a == 4 π && 3 b == 2 π);

rules = {(val_ == n_*sym_Symbol) :> (sym == val/n), 
         (val_ == sym_Symbol) :> sym == val};

ReverseSort /@ ((List @@ (List @@@ (expr // LogicalExpand)) /. rules))

(* {{b == 0, a == 0}, {b == π, a == 0}, {b == 0, a == π}, {b == π, 
  a == π}, {b == (4 π)/3, a == (2 π)/3}, {b == (2 π)/3, 
  a == (4 π)/3}} *)
```

Alternatively,

```
ReverseSort /@ ((expr // LogicalExpand) /. {Or -> List, And -> List} /. rules)

(* {{b == 0, a == 0}, {b == π, a == 0}, {b == 0, a == π}, {b == π, 
  a == π}, {b == (4 π)/3, a == (2 π)/3}, {b == (2 π)/3, 
  a == (4 π)/3}} *)

% === %%

(* True *)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ClearAll[reOrg]

reOrg = ReplaceAll[Or | And -> List] @* Map[Reduce[#, {b, a}] &];
```

***Example:***

```
ClearAll[a, b, expr]

expr = ((b ==  0 || b == π) && (a == 0 || a == π)) || 
  (3 a == 2 π && 3 b == 4 π) || (3 a == 4 π && 3 b == 2 π);


reOrg @ expr
```

> ```
> {{b == 0, a == 0}, {b == 0, a == π}, {b == π, a == 0}, {b == π, a == π},  
>  {b == (4 π)/3, a == (2 π)/3}, {b == (2 π)/3, a == (4 π)/3}}
> ```

```
TeXForm @ Column @ %
```

> $\begin{array}{l}
>  \{b=0,a=0\} \\
>  \{b=0,a=\pi \} \\
>  \{b=\pi ,a=0\} \\
>  \{b=\pi ,a=\pi \} \\
>  \left\{b=\frac{4 \pi }{3},a=\frac{2 \pi }{3}\right\} \\
>  \left\{b=\frac{2 \pi }{3},a=\frac{4 \pi }{3}\right\} \\
> \end{array}$